# Ruby haml dynamic table th

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In my rails app i need to read from csv file some data, after display it in view, but main trouble is that it is table with own number of rows in each file...
For example a.csv include row A, B, C, b.csv - A,B...
But how to do that number of th is generated automaticaly? 
For example:

```
%table.table.table-striped
  %tr
    %th
      id Заказа
    %th
      id клиента
    %th
      Общая сумма
    %th
      Статус
    %th
      Открыт
    %th
    %th
  -@orders.each do |o|
    %tr
      %td
        = o.id
      %td
        = o.user.email
      %td
        %b
          = o.totalcost
      %td
        %b
          = o.orderstatus.name
      %td
        = o.created_at
      %td
        = link_to "Подробнее", admin_order_path(o), :class => "btn btn-primary"
      %td
        = link_to "Редактирование", edit_admin_order_path(o), :class => "btn btn-warning"
```

Here i have 7 rows... But how to do, something like:

```
%table.table.table-striped
  %tr
    %th.each
      = i + 1
```

So that in browser i see rows headers 1,2,3 and data for them?

So how to set dynamic header quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I get what you are trying to achieve but to *just generate th dynamically* you can use something like the following. You will probably want to replace the `4` with a variable.

```
%table.table.table-striped
  %thead
    %tr
      - 4.times do |num|
        %th= num+1
```

Comment: main trouble is in your case with 4, i didn't know exactly what i will have: 4 or 20... so i need just to replace -4.times with -n.times

Comment: Well, you probably use the standard library CSV, right? If you do `arr_of_arrs = CSV.read("./a.csv")` it returns an array of arrays (array of rows, each array has array of columns), so then you can get the `n` just by `arr_of_arrs.first.length`.

Comment: ok, also how than display array if arrays using each? (quantity is same as in thead tr's)  - ooloollo.each do |o| - o.each do |k| = k[:num+1] like this?